# Aligning elements of various widths to a grid without affecting the width of the entire column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to align items with various widths to a grid.
Using a `min-width` attribute, short elements can be aligned like that, but if an element is too wide, it will disrupt the alignment of the following elements in that row:
(apparently I'm not allowed to embed pictures. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF2Mg.png)

What I would like to accomplish, is that after a long item, the following one will snap to the next "grid position", as I've mocked up here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tFr5.png)

I do not want there to be line-breaks in an item, and if at all possible, I'd like to avoid using JS.

Using a simple flexbox will of course not accomplish that, but it's the closest I've gotten to what I want.

```css
#content {
  color: black;
}
.container {
  width: 275px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;

  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;

  min-width: 55px;
  margin: 2.5px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 2a</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 2b</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 4 with a long name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 6a</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 6b</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 7</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 8</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also looked into using grids or tables, but could not find a way for an element to span as many columns as are needed to fit its width.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fully dynamic solution, as you will have to do some styling on the specific item that is wider than the other items.

Transform the layout into a `grid`-layout, apply `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(55px, 1fr));` which will make it a 4 column layout, where each item is at least 55px wide (better layout control than applying `min-width` on each item, IMO).

Target the item that is wider than the rest with `nth-child` or give it a specific class and use that instead, apply `grid-column: span 3` which will make the item span into 3 columns inside a single row, and then give it `max-width: fit-content`. This way, the specific item's width will only be as wide as it has content to fill it up.

```css
#content {
  color: black;
}

.container {
  width: 275px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  /* minmax 55px instead of min-width 55px on each item */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(55px, 1fr));
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  margin: 2.5px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column: span 3;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 2a</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 2b</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 4 with a long name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 5</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 6a</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 6b</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 7</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span>Item 8</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. A fully dynamic solution would of course be ideal, but I'm starting to think that might not be possible without additional scripting.
I'll keep the question open for now, just in case, but if there are no other suggestions, I'll go with that.